# Jobs not running automatically in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, job-scheduling

All the jobs i have on my oracle database and not running, even though their state is scheduled and they run manually, i guess i'm missing some sort of privilidge or some configuration done incorrectly

[image]

I was wondering if anyone had this sort of problem? and how they fixed it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Seems like my problem was that the sys had job_queue_processes value=0 ,

i simply ran the command

> Blockquote

```
alter system set job_queue_processes=1000;
```

any my problem was fixed.

to verify your default value:

```
 select value from v$parameter where name='job_queue_processes';
```